Non defined resolution in Copernicus data - No DIMVAR
I am trying to use future temperature data for my analysis for the Mediterranean Region. I want to use high resolution data and thus i selected from CDS copernicus this dataset: Temperature and precipitation climate impact indicators from 1970 to 2100 derived from European climate projections
https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/datasets/sis-hydrology-meteorology-derived-projections?tab=overview
The projection should be in lambert_azimuthal_equal_area and in 5km. When I try to import it and read it in R, I get the warning "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named x BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point".
Also, when i print the inserted data, i dont get a reference system and the resolution is 1 by 1..completely wrong.

This is the API from the copernicus site that someone can request:
import cdsapi

dataset = "sis-hydrology-meteorology-derived-projections"
request = {
    "product_type": "essential_climate_variables",
    "variable": ["2m_air_temperature"],
    "processing_type": "bias_corrected",
    "variable_type": "absolute_values",
    "time_aggregation": ["daily"],
    "horizontal_resolution": "5_km",
    "experiment": ["rcp_8_5"],
    "rcm": "cclm4_8_17",
    "gcm": "ec_earth",
    "ensemble_member": ["r12i1p1"],
    "period": ["2020"]
}

client = cdsapi.Client()
client.retrieve(dataset, request).download()

The commands I used are something like this in R:
## library(terra)
 example_dataset <- rast("example.nc") 
example_dataset

